# Answers removed from question

Tags: support

This is regarding the following post:

[Content-Security-Policy hash of script](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58789/content-security-policy-hash-of-script)

OP states the following and then goes on to show examples.

> I've toyed with this for over an hour but still am unable to generate a hash that matches examples

My answer was how to use `PowerShell` to generate the CSP hashes OP was having trouble with. However it was "deleted by moderator" which "cannot be undeleted". The moderator posted this in the comments.

> This does not answer the question. Please read our How to Answer page for guidance.

There was another post showing how to achieve the same results using `java`. It already had three votes proving it useful. I can only assume it was removed for the same reason as my post.

This question has fairly high traffic with 10k+ views and certainly helped me with creating a CSP. Thus why I wanted to contribute a `PowerShell` option.

I would like for my post and the java example restored as they both contribute to OP and will help anyone arriving at this post in the future.

If they cannot be restored, I would like to know that adding my answer via another post will not ignite a quarrel.

Comment: I'm not sure. It seems on-topic to me. It could just be a mistake (moderators need to delete a _lot_ of answers all the time, so it's easy for an innocent one to get hit). Wait until a moderator replies.

Answer (score 1):

The two deleted posts do not answer the question - all they do is show how to generate a CSP script hash. That isn't the question.

The accepted answer which states "UPDATE: it seems script hashes are not supported in the Chrome release version. My test only works in Chrome Canary (when using script-src, not default-src)" does provide an answer

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. I understand and agree with @forest. Hopefully you and/or fellow moderators can take a moment to restore the posts. The answers are not worth deleting.